# Ionic Responsive Grid merge columns

Tags: ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 Responsive Grid system to create a table which holds text information.

When it comes to the table header, the header consists of two lines. In the first line, I want some columns to span (merge) over several other columns of the second line:

```
|col1               |col2               |col3          |
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col1|col2|col3|col4|col1|col2|col3|
```

How can I achieve this using the `<ion-grid> <ion-row> <ion-col>` tags?

Comment: How should your grid be "responsive" in this scenario? In your example you are using 11 columns for the "second header line", this suggests that your table has 11 column. How should it be displayed in a small screen?

Comment: It does not have to be responsive as I am developing for iPad only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got the answer. What you can do is:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-4></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-3></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1></ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Comment: But this again makes the columns width very static. It does not care about the text within the column cell anymore...